# {exp:playa:total_children} > 1 not returning in conditional without var output

Tags: add-on, playa, pixelandtonic

I'm trying to show data conditionally based on a relationship having more than 1 child (see below). When I output the var `{exp:playa:total_children field="cf_lookbook_products" entry_id="{entry_id}"}` anywhere in the DOM, the conditional returns true, however if I do not include it, then it returns false always. That var also returns the correct number of children.

```
{if {exp:playa:total_children field="cf_relationship_field" entry_id="{entry_id}"} > 1}
content here
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put your conditional inside of your `{exp:channel:entries ...}` tag for the `{entry_id}` to work.

If that doesn't help, what code do you have around this conditional?

UPDATE

Change your quotes to look like this

```
{if "{exp:playa:total_children field='cf_relationship_field' entry_id='{entry_id}'}" > 1}
content here
{/if}
```

Comment: Conditional is in the loop. I literally have the var dumping in to a data attribute the line before that. When the var is present, the conditional works. Conditional only, no beuno.

Comment: Okay. See update.